# Ionic view doesn't render ng-repeat with fetched data from API

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

I am trying to display list of data fetched from API. **When the page loads it says errors array is undefined. but console prints the array.**

Here is what I have done so far.

**update.html**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="e in errorList">
      <ion-label>{{e.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value=""></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

I have tried sending as nav params. calling fetching function on constructor and ionViewWillEnter()

**update.ts**

```
export class AboutPage {
  errorList: any;
  error: string;
  errors: {};
  nav: NavController;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private errorService: ErrorServiceProvider) {
  this.nav = navCtrl;
  this.error = "";
  this.errors = this.navParams.get('errors');
  this.errorList = [];
 }

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.fetchErrors();
}

fetchErrors() {
  this.errorService.getErrors()
   .then(data => {
     this.errorList = data;
     console.log(this.errorList);
});
 }

selectError() {
    console.log(this.errors);
    console.log(this.errorList);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a silly mistake here, instead of **`ng-repeat`** use **`ngFor`** since it is angular, also Use an elvis operator to check the value is present

```
<ion-item ngFor="let e in errorList">
      <ion-label>{{e?.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value=""></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: No errors. but not running ng-repeat. fetchErrors() function prints the correct value. but it is not appear on view.

Comment: still not working. with elvis operator it runs without error. but in the normal way it says undefined doesn't have name attribute.

Comment: you need to read about angular2 , you need to use observable and subscribe here